# Can python shell have some pre-input?

Tags: python, linux, command-line

When testing in python shell, I always have to type some import like:

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Jun 24 2010, 15:23:27) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import sys
>>>import datetime
```

Can someone help me to automatically finish these? It means I run some command to enter python shell it has already done import for me, and a python shell waiting for me to continue type command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
python -i -c "import sys; import datetime;"
```

More info:

```
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
```

&

```
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with the commands you want to execute during startup, and set the environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` to the location of that file. The interactive interpreter will then load and execute that file. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interactive-startup-file

On a sidenote, you might want to consider [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) as an improved Python shell when working in interactive mode.

Comment: That's the way always run when startup, i just want to specify it sometimes, maybe my question is not clear, but thanks anyway.